# Laravel password strength validation

Tags: laravel

Is there any better way to validate password, I know below

'password' => 'required|
min:6|
regex:/^.*(?=.{3,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[\d\x])(?=.*[!$#%]).*$/|
confirmed',

Comment: Use the [`Password Rule Object`](https://laravel-news.com/password-validation-rule-object-in-laravel-8) available in Laravel since 8.39, see the [official docs fore more information](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#validating-passwords).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a much better solution from the [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#validating-passwords):

> ```
> use Illuminate\Validation\Rules\Password;
>
> // Require at least 8 characters...
> Password::min(8)
>  
> // Require at least one letter...
> Password::min(8)->letters()
>  
> // Require at least one uppercase and one lowercase letter...
> Password::min(8)->mixedCase()
>  
> // Require at least one number...
> Password::min(8)->numbers()
>  
> // Require at least one symbol...
> Password::min(8)->symbols()
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#validating-passwords) as well

Neither Just try below,

```
'password' => [
            'required',
            'string',
            'min:10',             // must be at least 10 characters in length
            'regex:/[a-z]/',      // must contain at least one lowercase letter
            'regex:/[A-Z]/',      // must contain at least one uppercase letter
            'regex:/[0-9]/',      // must contain at least one digit
            'regex:/[@$!%*#?&]/', // must contain a special character
        ],
```